# Pasting only numbers from the Clipboard

Tags: android, android-edittext, clipboardmanager

`InputType` of `EditText` in my application is `number`, only. How can I paste only numbers from clipboard to this `EditText`, if text in clipboard contains both numbers and letter?

Comment: You can't do that with xml, but you can do that with the help of your code in Java or Kotlin

Comment: Yes, I need to do it programmatically

Comment: Please check out the solution.

Comment: you not understand my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:** There are 2 things which came up.

**Firstly**: As I've tested your question, if you have set `EditText` as `android:inputType="number"` then it behaves exactly how you want. If you paste an alphanumeric string then it shows only number. It doesn't show Alphabets or any special characters at all. This was tested in my device `Android 7.1.1 (API25)`.

**Secondly**: If You still want to use a workaround which suits your need then you can use `TextWatcher`:

- Step1: Make an `EditText` global object in which you will paste your `String`, and initialize it:

  ```
  EditText editText;
  ```

  then in your `onCreate()`:

  ```
  editText = findViewById(R.id.your_editText);
  ```
- Step2: Add the `TextWatcher`

  ```
  editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
      @Override
      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

      }

      @Override
      public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
          ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
          try {
              CharSequence txt = clipboard.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0).getText();
              String str = getOnlyNumbers(txt.toString());
              editText.setText(str);
          } catch (Exception e) {
              return;
          }
      }
  });
  ```
- Step3: Add the below method in your class to rescue only numbers:

  ```
  public String getOnlyNumbers(String str) {

      str = str.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");

      return str;

  }
  ```

I hope this will help. If you have any doubts, please comment below.

Answer (score -1):

### Yes its possible

```
        final ClipboardManager myClipboard;
        final ClipData[] myClip = new ClipData[1];
        final int[] voterid;
        voterid= new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4};
```

### using Base adapter

```
        farea.setText(voterid);

        farea.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                myClip[0] = ClipData.newPlainText("text", voterid);
                myClipboard.setPrimaryClip(myClip[0]);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Text Copied",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```