# Pasting only numbers from the Clipboard for Jetpack Compose TextField

Tags: android, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose, textfield

I have a not perfect solution and will update it later.
How can I paste only numbers from clipboard to this TextField, if text in clipboard contains both numbers and letter?

There is a similar question but it is for EditText which is not jetpack compose UI.

[Pasting only numbers from the Clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53279681/pasting-only-numbers-from-the-clipboard)